# Token Request Failed: Remote Server returned error (400) while fetching the token

Tags: sharepoint-online, .net, oauth

My Requirement is to retrieve a document from SharePoint online using a .NET console application. I followed the steps in [this link](http://blog.symprogress.com/2013/11/call-sharepoint-online-csom-from-an-external-application/)  . But I get a failure

> Token request failed.
> {"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."}
>
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2S2SClient.Issue(String securityTokenServiceUrl, OAuth2AccessTokenRequest oauth2Request)

Any suggestions would be of great help